# Desocultar tabla de BD SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguien sabe como desocultar una tabla de una BD?, lo que pasa es que cuando hago select a la tabla si me muestra los regsitros que contiene, pero cuando la busco en el explorador de objetos en la BD  en donde se ubica no se visualiza, entonces no se que este pasando con esa tabla

Comment: ¿Haz probado darle refresh/refrescar a la carpeta de tablas?

Comment: @AlexVarela si le di refrescar

Comment: Esta raro, no puedes ocultar ningún objeto como si fuera un archivo común. ¿Usas otros esquemas aparte de dbo, podría ser que la buscas en el esquema equivocado? O la creaste en un servidor y en el explorador tenes otro.

Comment: Esto parece un error de Capa 8